# Field inheritance on Java

Tags: java, inheritance, field

Are fields only inherited "one level up"?

By that I mean that if I have a Superclass to a Class, which then has a Subclass, and the Superclass has a field, the Class will inherit it and the Subclass won't. Is this correct?

And if it is, is there a way to make the Subclass automatically inherit the field from the Superclass given that, as I understand it, there's no way to inherit from two classes at once?

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to answer. I realize my question may be impractical and in reality you'd probably just override the field or something, but I'm not trying to do anything specific, just trying to learn how Java works. Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int entero;

    protected void method(){
        entero=1;
    }




public class SubClass extends Class {

    public SubClass(){}

}


public class Class extends SuperClass {

    public Class(){}




}



    public static void main(String[] args){
    Class object= new Class();
    SubClass subobject= new SubClass();
/*This is where I get an error, why?*/ 
        subobject.entero=2;
/*This one is fine*/
        object.entero=2;
        object.method();
        System.out.println(object.entero);
        }
```

Comment: I assume you are talking about protected field, are you?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this line: " I have a Superclass to a Class, which then has a Subclass, and the Superclass has a field, the Class will inherit it and the Subclass won't." It's a little ambiguous.

Comment: @SteveP. `class SuperClass { protected int x; } class Class extends SuperClass {} class SubClass extends Class { }` clarified?

Comment: You can't override fields. Please tell us which problem you're trying to solve, preferrably with code.

Comment: Thank you, @LuiggiMendoza. That's exactly what I meant. Why is it that I can't access it directly?

Comment: Yes, @RohitJain. The field is protected.

Comment: @ermyuriel I think I may know what's going on with you not being able to access your super class' `protected` field. Check the edit in my answer.

Comment: Your SubClass doesn't extend Class nor SuperClass. That's why it doesn't have any `entero` field.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, I didn't see that he posted the code.  Nonetheless, the information may be useful to you (ermyuriel).

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, thank you. The code was just something I typed up quickly to illustrate my question, I was mostly intereste din the "why". Thank youi for taking the time to answer.

Comment: The real code matters. If your code was as you describe, and was syntactically correct, you wouldn't have an error. So post the real code, and the exact and complete error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any class `B` than `extends` a class `A`, will inherit `A's` fields.  If a class `C extends B`, `C` will inherit all non-private instance fields and methods from `A` and `B`, ie transitivity holds.

If a field is `private`, then one cannot directly change it from a subclass; however, you can get around this by using setter/getter methods.

If a field is `protected`, then a subclass has direct access to it.

**EDIT 1:**

In a comment you say that the field is `protected`, but you still can't access it from a subclass.  The only thing I can think of is that you have a situation like this:

```
class A
{
   protected int x; 
}

class B extends A
{
   private int x; 
}

class C extends B
{
   private int z = x;
}
```

This would **NOT** work because by declaring `x` again in `B`, you are hiding the `x` field from `A`.  So, now `C` sees `x` as `B's` `private` variable `x`, which you do not have access to.

**EDIT 2**:
I'm not going to remove the above edit, because it's informative, but now that you posted your code, it's because your `SubClass` does not actually `extend` anything (this was later fixed in an edit).

Comment: Thank you. I have added my code to the question. I don't think I'm doing that, but I can't access the field from the subclass.

Comment: Look at our two pieces of code.  I `extend` for both `B` and `C`.  Your 'Subclass' doesn't `extend` anything.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I typed that up quickly to illustrate my question and didn't notice. Thank you very much for answering.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance in Java is transitive.

If your classes are *Superclass < Class < Subclass*, then Subclass inherits all the non-private instance fields and methods provided by Superclass not overridden or hidden by Class or Subclass.

One level of inheritance is specified by the Java Language Specification, [section 8.4.8: Inheritance, Overriding and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces all abstract
>   and non-abstract methods of the superclass and superinterfaces that are public,
>   protected, or declared with default access in the same package as C, and are neither
>   overridden (§8.4.8.1) nor hidden (§8.4.8.2) by a declaration in the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have classes that are:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public void methodName() {}
    //SuperClass's stuff
}

public class MidClass extends SuperClass {
    //MidClass's stuff
}

public class SubClass extends MidClass {
    //SubClass's Stuff
}
```

Then it is perfectly valid to have in your main method:

```
SubClass sc = new SubClass();
sc.methodName();
```